# What does “factor=1.2” mean in the bootstrap function

Tags: r

I can't understand how *factor=1.2* combines the resulting two sets of bootstrap distribution statistics, and I don't understand why factor=1.2，Why not other coefficients

this is my code

```
bs = bootstrap(m_m, no_of_sims = 1000, threads = 1)
hist(bs$bootstraps[, 2], breaks = "fd")
hist(bs$bootstraps[, 3], breaks = "fd")
plot(jitter(bs$bootstraps[, 2], factor = 1.2), bs$bootstraps[, 3])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not from the bootstrap function, it's in the `jitter` function, see the documentation. It's the factor how much random noise you add to each point.